# js submenu effect appearance

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the fade in effect of this submenu with an instant appear effect (0sec delay).

[image]

the magic happens in this section of the assets/js/`app.min.js` file, and I suppose that I have to modify the `dropdown.fadeIn()` function, but I have no idea how:

```
that.hoverIntent(function() {
                        that.addClass("sfHover"), dropdown.fadeIn(), $(this).find(">a").addClass("active");
                    }, function() {
                        that.removeClass("sfHover"), dropdown.hide(), $(this).find(">a").removeClass("active");
                    }), children.hoverIntent(function() {
                        that.addClass("sfHover"), $(this).find(">.sub-menu").fadeIn(), $(this).find(">a").addClass("active");
                    }, function() {
                        that.removeClass("sfHover"), $(this).find(">.sub-menu").hide(), $(this).find(">a").removeClass("active");
                    });
```

live preview [here](http://goo.gl/DkuFmq).
Any thoughts? tks.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for, but you can just add `0` to the `fadeIn()` to remove the animation time/delay. like `fadeIn(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options

1. Replace the `fadeIn()` with `show(0)` so that their will be not delay or transition or animation at all.
2. If you want to keep `fadeIn()` for reusability purpose set it to `fadeIn(0)`.

Comment: I've done that.even with the show(0) there is still a little delay please compare with [this](http://demo.themerain.com/charm/) site.Any thoughts?

Comment: the link you gave uses css `:hover` pseudo class, I'll be updating my answer.

Comment: oh seems to run faster :) I appreciate it.

Comment: `#full-menu .full-menu > li:hover > ul {
  display: block !Important;
}` this css code must do